# nginx sub uri on another root

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I'm stuck on an nginx rule :

I have to use Nginx on our monitoring server, it uses Zabbix. I succesfully configured nginx for zabbix so that I can access *monit.domain.com* and it sends me to zabbix).

But I cannot setup *monit.domain.com/dashboard* so it displays the content of */usr/share/dashboard/pages*, that is php too (well, only index.php matters and you guessed it, it's my dashboard).

Here is the dashboard specific nginx conf : inside /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/monitoring.conf :

```
server {
    ######## server stuff with /location and ssl certs
    location /dashboard {
        alias /usr/share/dashboard/pages/index.php;
    }
}
```

Using root is ill advised following nginx best practices (and doesn't work, I tried anyway).

EDIT : here is the error I get in Nginx log :

`[error] 8247#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: monit.domain.com, request: "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "monit.domain.com"`

Can anyone suggest me whre to look at, thank you.

Comment: When you're requesting `dashboard` you are actually requesting `dashboard/index.php` and you have defined `index.php` in your `alias` Change it to `alias /usr/share/dashboard/pages/`

Comment: might be worth removing the "zabbix" tag, it doesn't touch zabbix at all and is about nginx redirects, i guess

Comment: @Richlv Just did this.

Comment: @Drifter104 : well, I changed the alias, and I still get the same error. The thing is that I want to request index.php.

Comment: Have you got `index index.php;` anywhere in the config?

Comment: @Drifter104 yes, but in the end, I found what I needed to do but even though that is not recommended by a best practice from nginx, it's required for my case to use a new root declaration and nest another php déclaration.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it to work like it should with this cofiguration:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name monit.domain.com;
    index index.php;
    root /usr/share/zabbix;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
    ssl on;
    # SSL stuff

    location / {
            root /usr/share/zabbix;
    }

    location /dashboard {
            root /usr/share;
            location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "
                 #many parameters
            ";
            #fastcgi_stuff .....
    }
```

So in the end, redefining a new root and nest a php segment to specify that it should be interpreted works.

Comment: You may not need the root directive for the first location block, as it is the same as the root for server block. Probably, I am wrong.